# "Looks like someone is on their way" without anyone arriving!

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Tonight, I've opened up my island  to 3 random visitors at a time, using a dodo code sharing site.

But quite often, me and the visitors will get to see the 'looks like someone is on their way'/'looks like someone's leaving' banner, freezing us... but without someone actually leaving or arriving!

Does anyone know why this might happen, and what I can do about it/what I can ask my visitors to do/don't?

(It doesn't seem someone has a window open, since we're all just standing here on the beach making wishes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tends to happen when there is a connection error when someone tries to use a dodo code to come to your island.

Unfortunately, I don't know what causes the error - I got it when there was a visitor limit reached on the destination island, but there could be many possible causes (Nintendo's netcode tends to be very poor in this regard).  Either way, the solution is to tell players to stop attempting to fly to your island until the issue is resolved.